# Water from refrigerator tastes bad after 5 day power outage

Tags: refrigerator

The water from refrigerator tastes very bad after 5 day power outage. Everything rotted in the fridge and we had to clean it out after the power came back on. The fridge is fine now, but the water that feeds the ice machine and the chilled water spout still tastes pretty funky.

I tried to flush the system by running water through it for a while, that seems to help temporarily, but the funky taste came back.

This is the refrigerator that I have: http://www.sears.com/shc/s/p_10153_12605_04651073000P

This is the manual for it: http://www.managemylife.com/mmh/lis_pdf/OWNM/1006612L.pdf

Should I just change the water filter in the fridge, or will I have to flush the system some kind of cleaning agent?

How is this kind of thing normally handled?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I am guessing that the rest of the house has no issues with smell or taste of the water. My first step would be to empty the ice tray and wash it really well with a mix of baking soda and water mixed into a paste. While the ice tray is out carefully check the ice unit for any evidence of mold or odors. Change the filter. Purge the system by making and throwing out a couple of trays of ice. Fill and dispose of a couple of gallons of water out of the dipenser.

Comment: Unfortunately, I've already done all that 3-4 times :(

Comment: I would be very cautious about adding any chemicals to the system. Stop at or call an appliance repair center and get some advice from them.

Comment: Yeah, I wouldn't do that "off the cusp".  Would definitely need to be aware of an "established" method for handling this type of thing. The new water filter is coming tomorrow, so I'll see how that works.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to mikes' advice, consider changing the prefilter for the line that feeds a refrigerator, if there is one.

1. The most common setup is a line that comes up through the floor from the basement or sideways from a kitchen sink.
2. A refrigerator line is either a thin plastic tube or a thin copper tube.
3. Trace where the line comes through the floor or the cabinet to the refrigerator.
4. Follow it back to where it attaches to a larger pipe.
5. See if there is a canister somewhere along that line. It would be about 3 inches across and 6 to 12 inches in length.  That is a prefilter for the fridge.
6. If you find one, replace it also. Take it to a home center or plumbing supply store for a similar one. Brand is not an issue and there are pretty universal fittings to attach them.

Comment: There was not a pre-filter before. But I installed a 5 stage reverse osmosis system a few days ago. This water tastes great. And it tastes great coming out of the fridge after I purge the fridge lines.  But after refills and sets in the fridge for a day or so, it tastes funky again :(

Answer (score 1):

I had problems with the taste of the water as well.  When the line was originally installed they used a flexible metal line....had it changed to a clear plastic line and now the water tastes just fine...

Comment: This does not appear to have much to do with the poster's question, relating to a change caused by the power being out.